# flask-login reusable cookies

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-login

I am using `Flask-login` with `remember=False` (the only cookie is the `session` cookie). When copy-pasting the `session` cookie **after logging out**, for some reason the session is still valid and the user is logged in. Even though the logged out session was deleted properly in the *flask* `logout_user()` function - meaning that the `["user_id"]` was deleted from the `session` dictionary. It seems like the session is restored from the old cookie. can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

I do not really have a right answer for this yet, as I am investigating it myself, but there are a couple of points I would like to make here:

the logout_user() from Flask-login does not really seem to be invalidating the session. It just changes the 'session' cookie's value in the client (the browser). While in the backend this session is still alive.

An experiment to prove this would be: (a simple browser plugin like *CookieManager* can be used to perform this exercise)

1. login to the app
2. take a note of the 'session' cookie's value post successful login
3. now logout
4. now observer the 'session' cookie's value again. And you would
   notice that it has now changed.
5. Replace this value with the 'session'cookie's value previously noted
   in step 1 above.
6. Try visiting an internal authenticated page again.

**Result** : You would successfully be able to view an internal page without re-logging in, proving that the logout_user() never really invalidated the session but just changed the 'session' cookie in the client.

Howeverm, I am myself still taking a look into [flask-login logout_user() definition](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_login/utils.html#logout_user) and trying to make sense of it.

Comment: Thanks! I've found nice documentation for applying session management with `flask-login`: https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/docs/index.rst#alternative-tokens. Basically I replaced the `id` based token with `session` based token which is created and destroyed when user login and logout.

Answer (score 0):

I had This issue too. After diagnosing what i found is the decorator **@login_required** `*does not invalidate the User in server side after logout*`, which is a security threat. This will be a cake walk for a Hacker to hack your application since they can easily extract all the request and header data from developer tool of your browser and can again send request to you server from outside of the application.For ex: If you have used any API in your application the it will be very easy for Hacker to get all the request data and resend a request using POSTMAN.

I solved this issue by creating a separate decorator "@authentication_required" and used in place of "**@login_required**". then it worked for me,though @login_required is supposed to do the same.
So basically while logging in i generated a random string(token) and sent to database and same string(token) is added to session of flask i.e session["token"]="akhfkjdbfnd334fndf" use any random string generator function.(session object is globally available if u r using flask . u can very well add any field to session). and while logout i again generate a string(token) and update the old token with newly generated token in database. So what @authentication_required will do is it will get the token from session object and the token which is present in database and try to compare the value. if both are same then only @authentication_required will let the client access api.and dont forget to do session.clear() after logout_user().

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------#
#@authentication_required definition

def authentication_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            user_id=session['user_id'] #assigning "user_id" from flask session object to a variable "user_id"
            user=User_table.find_first(_id=user_id)#couhdb query syntax
            #comparing api_token sent to  session object at the login time with     api_token in sent to database at login time. If both doesn't matches then user is redirected to login page.
            if  not session["token"]==user.token:
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
            else:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:


            app.logger.info(Response('Request Did not came through header !', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Login failed'}))

            return redirect(url_for('login_to system'))

    return wrap
#---------------------------------------------------------------#
```

## -------------------------------------------------------

## login api code

```
@app.route('/login_to_system', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_to_system():
    form = LoginForm()

        user = User_table.find_first(username=form.username.data)
        login_user(user, remember=False)
        try:
            #Generating  an random api_token at login time and will send to db
            token_string=''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=14))
            user.token=token_string #assigning token_string value to field api_token in database.
            user.save() #saving the value in user table(using couch Db You can follow syntax as per you DB)
        except Exception as error:
            app.logger.error(str(error))
        app.logger.info("before setting api_token in session")   
        session["token"]= token_string #adding a "token" to session object

    #app.logger.info("Rendering login form")
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)

#-------------------------------------------------------#
#-----------------------------------#
#logout api code

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    try:
        user=User_table.find_first(_id=user_id)
        #Generating a random token while logging out and will overwrite eariler token sent at login time send to database.
        user.token=token_string=''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=17))
        user.save()

    except Exception as error:
        app.logger.error(str(error))
    logout_user()
    session.clear()#clearing session 
    return redirect(url_for('Home page'))
#-----------------------------------#
```

Note: Seems like login_required is not working fine for me thats why i had to create another decorator but login_required also does the same thing but its strange that it not working for me.