# Flask-login loads a user from remember cookie after logout

Tags: flask-login

The function logout_user sets marks session['_remember'] as 'clear'

```
    cookie_name = current_app.config.get('REMEMBER_COOKIE_NAME', COOKIE_NAME)
    if cookie_name in request.cookies:
        session['_remember'] = 'clear'
        if '_remember_seconds' in session:
            session.pop('_remember_seconds')
```

After login I am sending a request with remember cookie, the session object does not have '_remember' attribute. Therefore, the condition session.get('_remember') != 'clear' is True. As a result the user is loaded from remember cookie, even after logout:

```
cookie_name = config.get('REMEMBER_COOKIE_NAME', COOKIE_NAME)
has_cookie = (cookie_name in request.cookies and
              session.get('_remember') != 'clear')
if has_cookie:
    cookie = request.cookies[cookie_name]
    user = self._load_user_from_remember_cookie(cookie)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40030691/flask-login-reusable-cookies - for the similar issue.